# using zip.js to read a zip file via xmlhttp/ajax call on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, download, arraybuffer, zip.js

I am trying to :

1. Send a zip file via xmlhttp to the client
2. then read the file using [zip.js](http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/) and render its contents

I successfully receive the binary of the file i.e. the success callback is called but I get and error when I try to do **getEntries**.  I think the error is with the way of sending stream , please help.

**Error msg** :

> Error in reading zip file

My client side code (using angular) :

```
$http.get(window.location.origin + '/book/'+bookName,{responseType:"Blob"}).
success(function (data , error) {
    var a = new Uint8Array(data);
        //var dataView = new DataView(data);
        //var blob = new Blob(dataView.buffer);
    zip.useWebWorkers = true;
    zip.workerScriptsPath = '/js/app/';

    zip.createReader(new zip.BlobReader(data), function(reader) {

      // get all entries from the zip
      reader.getEntries(function(entries) {   //HERE I GET THE ERROR
        if (entries.length) {

          // get first entry content as text
          entries[0].getData(new zip.TextWriter(), function(text) {
            // text contains the entry data as a String
            console.log(text);

            // close the zip reader
            reader.close(function() {
              // onclose callback
              var a = 0;
            });

          }, function(current, total) {
            // onprogress callback
            var a = 0;
          });
        }
      });
    },
     function(error) {
      // onerror callback
        var a = 0;
    });


})
.error( function (data , error) {
    var a = 0;

});
```

My Server side code on Node:

```
router.get('/book/:bookName',function (req , res ) {


console.log('Inside book reading block : ' + req.params.bookName);
req.params.bookName += '.zip';

var filePath = path.join(__dirname,'/../\\public\\books\\' ,req.params.bookName );
var stat = fileSystem.statSync(filePath);

res.writeHead(200, {
    //'Content-Type': 'application/zip',
    'Content-Type': 'blob',
    'Content-Length': stat.size
});

var readStream = fileSystem.createReadStream(filePath);
// replace all the event handlers with a simple call to readStream.pipe()
readStream.pipe(res);   
});
```

Answer (score 4):

It is probable that you might have already found a solution. I faced the same problem today and this is how I solved it in plain javascript:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'assets/object/sample.zip', true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

xhr.onload = function(e) {
    // response is unsigned 8 bit integer
    var responseArray = new Uint8Array(this.response);
    var blobData = new Blob([responseArray], {
        type: 'application/zip'
    });
    zip.createReader(new zip.BlobReader(blobData), function(zipReader) {
        zipReader.getEntries(displayEntries);
    }, onerror);
};

xhr.send();
```

The problem I see in your code is that you are changing the value to Uint8Array and assigning it to `var a`, but still use the raw data in blobreader. Also the blob reader required blob and not an array. So you should have converted `var a` into blob and then used it for reading.

Comment: Downvote without a comment. You could at least share the reason.